# Typescript send data to server

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with send data to my server. I tried many things but I don't have idea for it. Ok first this is my class:

```
import {Father} from './Father';
import {Child} from './Child';

export class Family {
  public id: number;
  public father: Father
  public childList: Array<Child>
}
```

I want to send object Family to my server. This class should have object father and children list. I implemented family-service for it:

```
export class FamilyService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createFamily(family: Family): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}` + `/addFamily`, family);
}
```

And this is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-child',
  templateUrl: './create-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-child.component.css']
})
export class CreateChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('father') father: Father = new Father();
  family: Family = new Family();s
  child: Child = new Child();
  submitted = false;
  childList: Array<Child> = [];

  createFamily() {
    this.family.father = new Father();
    this.family.father = this.father;
    this.father.family = this.family;
    this.family.childList = new Array<Child>();
    this.family.childList = this.childList;
    this.familyService.createFamily(this.family).subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
    this.family = new Family();
  }
```

And when I run this code I always get error:

```
TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
```

This is my first step in Angular so if you can please help me.

Comment: (Side note: Some families have multiple fathers, and/or multiple mothers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong: You have a cyclical structure (object A refers to object B which refers to object A [perhaps indirectly]).

We can see that from this:

```
this.family.father = this.father;
this.father.family = this.family;
```

So, `family` refers to `father` which refers to `family`.

You'll need to create a non-cyclical structure in order to turn it into JSON, since JSON doesn't support cyclical structures. (You might only use the non-cyclical one when serializing.)

Comment: Thank you very much @T.J. Crowder for your help. Works fine.